# Reversing HTML grid data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html grid table which creates the table in js file and looks like this

```
   tbl_html = tbl_html + '<tbody>' +

                         '<td>' + yearconvert(yearr) + '</td>' +
                         '<td>' + starttime+ '</td>' +
                         '<td>' + endtime + '</td>';
```

There is a loop which gives the value of  year ,starttime ,endtime .  It displays it well but I want to reverse the result which I see in html grid .

```
for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    var starttime= Date.UTC(parseInt(matrix[i].start_time);
    var endtime = Date.UTC(parseInt(matrix[i -1]);
    var year =matrix[i].year;
}
```

[image]

I want to see last row will be the first row and others as follow
for example year , 11/2009 - 10/2009 - 09/2009 - 08/2009

[edit] That is to say, I only want to change the row order but not the column [/edit]

Any idea  to achieve it ?

Thanks

Comment: Clarify what you want the final result to look like, please.

Comment: If you want to reverse the table, just switch your `for` statement to `for (var i = matrix.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: Sure, but what have you tried? You can do this by making use of the `insertBefore` method that all html elements that may contain others has. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp

Comment: @user2407340 - even your comment is somewhat ambiguous. That said, you type english better than I could type your native language. As others have said, just create the table in the order that you want it. But if you want to re-order it once it exists, use the `insertBefore` method. You need to get a reference to the tbody element. You can then use insertBefore to append each row to the tbody before the item that is currently tbody.childNodes[1]. (0 indexes the header row) I'll write a solution.

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks for your time and effort ,  I am really appreciate .

Answer (score 2):

How about going through the matrix backwards?

```
for (var i = matrix.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var starttime= Date.UTC(parseInt(matrix[i].start_time);
        var endtime = Date.UTC(parseInt(matrix[i -1]);
        var year =matrix[i].year;

    tbl_html = tbl_html + '<tbody>' +

                             '<td>' + yearconvert(yearr) + '</td>' +
                             '<td>' + starttime+ '</td>' +
                             '<td>' + endtime + '</td>';
    }
```

Comment: That, or even just add tbl_html to the end instead of the beginning.

Comment: matrix[i -1]); will be a problem .

Comment: You told us that part of your code "displays it well", despite the fact that `matrix[i]` is clearly an object and not a number.

Comment: the current code works fine but I want to update it , that's why I typed it .

Comment: Do you want to not show a row for the 1st matrix entry, or do you want to show a blank end time?  Either got to >0 for 1st case, of add a i ? Date.UTC(parseInt(matrix[i -1]) : ''; for the 2nd case

Comment: matrix comes from an ajax call and it returns some array results like 0 ,1,2,....so on  so there is no any minus number in matrix array.

Comment: My point is, we lack sufficient information to correct `matrix[i-1]`, as you have told us very little about what `matrix` contains. I can only guess that `matrix[i].end_time` would be the right thing to use instead.

Comment: I see , yeah I am sorry regarding that the information loss . but I need to consume matrix endtime with an order that's why I used i-1 there

Comment: I think Blazemonger's point is that your code in your question (that you say works) starts with i = 0 and your endtime calculation does i-1, which will be -1. So, if your code works, my answer will work.  But, if it doesn't, that's another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just edit the JS

```
tbl_html = tbl_html + '<tbody>' +
                     '<td>' + starttime + '</td>' +
                     '<td>' + endtime+ '</td>' +
                     '<td>' + yearconvert(yearr) + '</td>';
```

Comment: I only want to change the row order but not the column

Comment: Sorry buddy, unfortunately i got the wrong end of the stick. It does seem however that with more information you could accomplish this much easier and we could help you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

Basically, we just iterate through the rows collection of the tbody element.
We insert rows with an increasing index before whichever row is the first one containing data. If the table has a header, the first data row is rows[1] - if the table doesn't have a header, the first data row is rows[0]. The row that we need to insert before is constantly changing, so we have to get a reference to it each time through the loop. Fortunately, the index remains the same - hence the use of `tbody.rows[firstRowIndex]` -whose contents do change, even though at first glance this may be erroneously seen as constant.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function makeTable()
{
    var table = newEl('table');
    table.id = 'myTable';
    var tbody = newEl('tbody');
    table.appendChild(tbody);

    var tr = newEl('tr');
    var i, j, n = 3;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        var curCell = newEl('th');
        curCell.appendChild( newTxt('Column ' + i) );
        tr.appendChild(curCell);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);

    for (j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        tr = newEl('tr');
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            var curCell = newEl('td');
            curCell.appendChild( newTxt('Cell: ' + (i + j*n) ) );
            tr.appendChild(curCell);
        }
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(table);
}

function onDocLoaded()
{
    makeTable();
}

function flipRows(tableId, hasHeaderRow)
{
    var tbl = byId(tableId);
    var tbody = tbl.childNodes[0];
    var i, n;
    n = tbody.rows.length;

    var firstRowIndex = 0;
    if (hasHeaderRow == true)
        firstRowIndex++;

    for (i=firstRowIndex+1; i<n; i++)
        tbody.insertBefore( tbody.rows[i], tbody.rows[firstRowIndex] );
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="flipRows('myTable', true)">Flip rows of this table</button><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var griddatayear = reversegridarray(arrayyear);
        var griddatastart = reversegridarray(arraystart);
        var griddataend = reversegridarray(arrayend);
        var griddatadur = reversegridarray(arrayduration);
        var size;
        function reversegridarray(gridarr) {
            var gridarrayresult = [];
            var myres;
            ii = gridarr.length;
            for (var i = ii - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                gridarrayresult.push(gridarr[i]);
            }
            size=gridarrayresult.slice(0).sort().indexOf(undefined);
            myres = gridarrayresult.filter(function (e) { return e });
            return myres;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < size ; i++) {


        tbl_html = tbl_html + '<tbody>' +

        //'<td>' + monthsupdated[i] + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + yearconvert(griddatayear[i]) + '</td>' +
                         '<td>' + griddatastart[i] + '</td>' + 
                         '<td>' + griddataend[i] + '</td>' +
                         '<td>' + griddatadur[i] + '</td>';

    }
```

issue is resolved